# Keep strings case-insensitively unique in a database

Tags: sql, database, unique, case-insensitive

I'd like to ensure that when a user wants to register a username in my system (web application), the user name is unique even if case is not regarded. So if a user named "SuperMan" is already registered, no other user must be allowed to register as "superman" or "SUPERman". This must be checked at database level.

In my current implementation, I do the following:

```
select count(*) from user where lower(name) = lower(?) for update;
-- If the count is greater than 0, abort with an error
-- Determine a new ID for the user
insert into user (id, name, …) values (?, ?, …);
```

I'm not sure whether the "for update" will lock the database far enough so that other users won't be able to register with an invalid name between the two SQL statements above. Probably it's no 100% safe solution. Unfortunately I cannot use unique keys in SQL because they will only compare case-sensitively.

Is there another solution to this? How about the following, to add more safety?

```
select count(*) from user where lower(name) = lower(?) for update;
-- If the count is greater than 0, abort with an error
-- Determine a new ID for the user
insert into user (id, name, …) values (?, ?, …);
-- Now count again
select count(*) from user where lower(name) = lower(?);
-- If the count is now greater than 1, do the following:
delete from user where id = ?;
-- Or alternatively roll back the transaction
```

Comment: As it comes to what DBMS support what, my current requirements are to support MySQL, SQLite and PostgreSQL, in this order. Other systems would be nice for the future though. Since PostgreSQL does not support collations in this way yet (it's on their TODO) and SQLite does not support Unicode very well (A = a, but Ä != ä), I'd probably want another solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I've done that is make a second column for the username that's either converted to all caps or all lower case.  That I put a unique index on that.  I use a trigger to generate the value in this other column so the code doesn't have to worry about it.

Come to think of it, you could use a function based index to get the same result:

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX user_name_ui1 ON user (lower(name))

Comment: The separate column seems the most portable and easiest to handle/understand solution. I'll see whether I'll leave it to the application to create the "normalised" value for the additional column or whether I'll use a trigger for that. Regarding SQLite's poor Unicode support (out of the box), I'll probably let iconv (in PHP) do the job.

Answer (score 4):

Your assumption that an unique constraint will compare case sensitively is incorrect. They will compare according to the **collation** of the column. All commercial databases worth talking about support collations. Simply choose a case insensitive collation for your column, and declare a unique constraint on it. See:

- [Character Sets and Collations That MySQL Supports](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html)
- [Using SQL Server Collations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144260.aspx)
- [Oracle Linguistic Sorting and String Searching](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch5lingsort.htm#NLSPG005)
- [SQLite collating sequences](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation)
- ...

Doing the enforcement by a lookup and before insert is not only extremely inefficient, is also incorrect under concurrency.

Comment: If you're using something like JDBC, you frequently do no not know which database you're using.  Anything that requires a DBMS specific solutions on the client side would break that portability.

Comment: Declaring a column collation and placing an unique index on it is obviously a DDL deployment time operation. There is no cross platform DDL, any application that is more than a simple demoware will run into insurmountably issues if it tries to do *any* deployment that claims works cross platform. There simply is basically **no** standard when it comes to DDL operations. Case in point, syntax like `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX user_name_ui1 ON user (lower(name))` is a pipe dream on MySQL or SQL Server since they don't support function-based indexes, which Oracle would support.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the way unique constraints work by changing the collation for that column: [Unique constraint on table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609676/unique-constraint-on-table-column)

Comment: I think that's going to be DBMS specific.  Using the generated column works pretty much with anything.  I also use that column for sorts where the code doesn't know which DBMS it's using.

Comment: @JOTN, I totally agree. While many SQL server packages support collation not all do (MSSQL, MySql, Sqlite do, but PostgreSQL does not), and the set of collations they support may vary. So using collation definitely limits you when you might want to switch to a different DBMS. I just thought it should be on the table as an option. I +1ed your answer though.